# Java: Input error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

When I use one object of class Scanner for two object of user defined class. Compiler skips some input taking line. As mentioned below.

```
1) Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);

2) GradeBook book1 = new GradeBook();
3) GradeBook book2 = new GradeBook();

//input for book1

4) variable1 = obj.nextInt();
5) book1.variable1 = variable1;
6) variable2 = obj.nextInt();
7) book1.variable1 = variable2;
8) variable3 = obj.nextInt();
9) book1.variable1 = variable3;

//input for book2

10) variable1 = obj.nextInt();
11) book2.variable1 = variable1;
12) variable2 = obj.nextInt();
13) book2.variable1 = variable2;
14) varibale3 = obj.nextInt();
15) book2.variable1 = variable3;
```

It skips line No 10 (it does not read this line `variable1 = obj.nextInt();`).

But when I use two different objects of Scanner class, one for book1 and second for book2, then it works fine.

Whats the problem, why happens like this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GradeTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try{
        Employee employee1 = new Employee();
        Employee employee2 = new Employee();

        String fName,lName;
        double salary;              

        System.out.print("Enter first name:");
        fName = input.nextLine();
        employee1.SetFName(fName);
        System.out.print("\nEnter last name:");             
        lName = inp.nextLine();
        employee1.SetLName(lName);
        System.out.print("\nEnter salary:");
        salary = inp.nextDouble();
        employee1.SetSalary(salary);

        System.out.printf("\n1:Updated Value \n FName : %s  LName : %s  Salary : %.2f ", employee1.GetFName(),employee1.GetLName(),employee1.GetSalary());

Systm.out.println("Enter data for second employee. \n");

        System.out.print("Enter first name:");
        lName = input.nextLine();
        employee2.SetFName(fName);
        System.out.print("\nEnter last name:");
        lName = input.nextLine();
        employee2.SetLName(lName);
        System.out.print("\nEnter salary:");
        salary = input.nextDouble();
        employee2.SetSalary(salary);

            System.out.printf("\n2:Initial Value \n FName : %s  LName : %s  Salary : %.2f ", employee2.GetFName(),employee2.GetLName(),employee2.GetSalary());
                }
        finally{
                inp.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
Enter first name: First Name1
Enter last name:  Last Name1                
Enter salary: 1500.00

Enter data for second employee.

Enter first name: First Name2
Enter last name:  Last Name2                
Enter salary: 1200.00
```

Actual output:

```
Enter first name: First Name1
Enter last name:  Last Name1                
Enter salary: 1500.00

Enter data for second employee.

Enter first name: 
Enter last name:  Last Name2                
Enter salary: 1200.00
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using `obj.nextLine()` in between those lines?

Comment: can you show actual vs expected output?

Comment: Post a compilable code sample, tell us the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Daniel , JB Nizet check post updated post.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually the Scanner behaving as designed. Here's how it works:

next() takes input from the stream up to the next instance of the delimiter (whitespace by default) and leaves the delimiter in place. nextLine() takes up to the next "\n" character, discards the newline, and returns the remainder, which may be zero.

Therefore, if you do next() followed by nextLine(), and the user enters just one token in the next() call, what will be left in the stream will be the "\n" character that next() doesn't take. Then nextLine() takes up to the "\n", which is the only thing, and throws "\n" away, and returns "".

It's a confusing implementation, I know.

tl;dr: Use a nextLine() to clear after a next().

NOTE: nextInt() is a just a call to next() followed by a parseInt(), so it behaves in this regard exactly as next() does.